# How to build a block on form submission?

Tags: 7, blocks, forms

I know how to build a block using these functions :

```
hook_block_info()
hook_block_configure()
hook_block_save()
hook_block_view()
```

But on a form submission a few information is saved into DB and based on those information one block must be created.  how do I can build a block in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will encourage you to look at [bean contributed module](https://drupal.org/project/bean). Using this you can create **block types** whose instances can be created using [bean_create](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/misc/bean!bean.module/function/bean_create/7.x) function.

Example snippet:

```
$values = array(
  'delta' => 'test_bean',
  'label' => t('Test Bean'),
  'title' => t('Test Bean'),
  'type' => some_block_type_that_you_will_create_through_UI,
  'view_mode' => 'default',
  'data' => array(
    'test_boolean' => FALSE,
    'test_string' => t('New String'),
    'test_array' => array(
      'test_array_1' => 'new_value',
    ),
  ),
);

$bean = bean_create($values);
```

The bean content (block) can then be placed around the site just like any other block.

Comment: what is the plugin_name? it reports this error: ` Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: `plugin_name` in the snippet above has the value for **block-type** for which a block is being created. The snippet was copied from `bean.test` file included in [bean module](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/bean-7.x-1.7.zip) itself. Please go through its documentation, its really simple to create one.

Comment: I'll update the snippet above to remove the confusion.

Comment: I executed the code but no block generated! it also has some inconsistency: I use `_block_rehash($theme);` statement which returns all of the blocks. the `bean` command make a warning in my website!\

Comment: @Drupalist Can you update the question with the code that you ran?

Comment: it wasn't because of the `Bean` why the warning reported. I ran your code and no block created! besides that what is `some_block_type_that_you_will_create_through_UI` ? I searched for Bean type but found nothing.

Comment: The attached snippet is not ready to be used yet. Please look into bean.test file in bean module to understand how to use bean_create function. It has been used at lines 160, 165, 200, 207 and 231. Enough examples added in that file. And `some_block_type_that_you_will_create_through_UI` is really what is says. You will have to first download and enable bean module, then create a block-type using its admin UI(bean_admin_ui module), before creating blocks of that type.

Comment: Please see [this 7:35 minutes video on BEAN module on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu1YNy-BNG8) and things will be clearer.